# How to generate an n-dimensional matrix in SymPy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

How can I generate a matrix A with n rows and 2 columns in SymPy where n is a symbolic variable in Python?

```py
import sympy
n = sympy.Symbol("n")
A = sympy.Matrix.zeros(n,2)
```

It went wrong.
**TypeError**: cannot determine truth value of Relational

I want to solve this problem and make it possible to generate a matrix like this.

Comment: Your comment indicates that you want to be able to modify the entries of the matrix but that cannot be possible for a matrix with a symbolic number of rows because we don't even know how many rows it has to know if any given entry exists or not. MatrixSymbol can be used to make a matrix with symbolic shape but you cannot modify its entries. If that is not suitable then the question needs to be clarified.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.